# For any Gaussian variable $z$ with zero mean, $\langle \exp(z)\rangle = \exp\left(\frac12\langle z^2\rangle\right)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, stochastic-processes

I read this in a textbook on stochastic processes and I would appreciate it if somebody could clarify (if this is incorrect) and explain why this is true.

Comment: Complete the square in the integral?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2).$ Then
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(e^X) & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, \frac{dx} \sigma = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\sigma u} e^{-u^2/2} \, du \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left( \frac{-1} 2 \left( u^2 - 2\sigma u{} \right) \right) \, du \\[10pt] & = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left( \frac{-1} 2 \left( u^2 + 2\sigma u + \sigma^2 \right) \right) \, du \cdot \Big( e^{\sigma^2/2} \Big) \\[10pt]
& = e^{\sigma^2/2} \text{ if the factor to the left of that is equal to 1.}
\end{align}
But the factor to the left of $e^{\sigma^2/2}$ is
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(u+\sigma)^2/2} \, du = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-v^2/2} \, dv = 1.
$$